# Add ann item to a ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to achieve, that the Legend has the title "Year" and displays the blue bar as a small rectangle for "2016" together with the circle and triangle for years "2012" and "2008". Any ideas how could I achieve that? Because now I only get the legend for the plotted points data.

Reproducible example:

```
# packages needed

library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)
library(lubridate)

# downlaoding the dataset
ilc_di11 <- get_eurostat("ilc_di11", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# manipulating data
df <- ilc_di11 %>% filter(age=="TOTAL",
                         geo %in% c("EU28", "BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"),
                         sex=="T",
                         year(time) %in% c("2008", "2012", "2016"))%>%
        spread(time, values) %>%
        rename(`2008`=`2008-01-01`,
               `2012`=`2012-01-01`,
               `2016`=`2016-01-01`)%>%
        gather(var, values, 5:6)

# plotting data
ggplot(data=df)+
        geom_bar(aes(x=reorder(geo, `2016`), y=`2016`),
                 stat = "identity", 
                 position = "dodge",
                 fill="steelblue")+
        geom_point(aes(x=reorder(geo, `2016`), y=values, 
                       shape=var,
                       color=var),
                   size=3)+
        labs(title="Pajamų nelygybė nustatyta pagal S80/S20 santykį", 
             subtitle="Šaltinis: Eurostat (ilc_di11)", 
             x="Šalys", 
             y="Santykis")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions, one of them is too pass a dummy `data.frame` to a separate `geom_point` layer. Set the size 0 of this point so it wouldn't show up in plot, but assign color and shape to it.

```
ggplot(df, aes(shape = var, color = var)) +
    geom_bar(aes(reorder(geo, `2016`), `2016`), 
             stat = "identity", position = "dodge", fill = "steelblue", color = NA) +
    geom_point(aes(x, y),
               data.frame(x = Inf, y = Inf, var = "2016", var = "2016"),
               size = 0) +
    geom_point(aes(reorder(geo, `2016`), values, shape = var, color = var), 
               size = 3) +
    labs(title    = "Pajamų nelygybė nustatyta pagal S80/S20 santykį", 
         subtitle = "Šaltinis: Eurostat (ilc_di11)", 
         x        = "Šalys", 
         y        = "Santykis",
         color    = "Year",
         shape    = "Year")
```

[image]